# How to get array from the user and print to him the repeated numbers and how many are the repeated numbers? C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to ask a user to input some numbers and I should find out the repeating numbers and how many them so if he type 2 three times I should tell him the 2 is repeating number and occurs 3 times

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;


    namespace Task4
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int i, j;
                Console.WriteLine("Type repeating numbers and I will find them: ");
                int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());
                int[] num = new int[size];


                for (i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
                {
                    num[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());
                    for (j = i + size; j < num.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (num[i] == num[j])
                            Console.Write(num[i] + " ");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would use [GroupBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've written any code that attempts to find the repeating numbers. Why don't you make an attempt at it?

Comment: @itsme86 so how I should use it? because I have little experience with c#

Comment: @AhmedAdel I linked you to the documentation that even has examples of how to use it. I'm not going to do your homework assignment for you.

Comment: @mason I can not figure it out, because I have little experience with c#

Comment: @itsme86 ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) to store the count associated with each number entered.

Output:

```
Type repeating numbers, one per line, and I will find them ('quit' to end).
Number ('quit' to end): 1
1 added
Number ('quit' to end): 2
2 added
Number ('quit' to end): 3
3 added
Number ('quit' to end): 2
2 added
Number ('quit' to end): 4
4 added
Number ('quit' to end): 2
2 added
Number ('quit' to end): 5
5 added
Number ('quit' to end): 6
6 added
Number ('quit' to end): 7
7 added
Number ('quit' to end): 6
6 added
Number ('quit' to end): 8
8 added
Number ('quit' to end): quit
Results:
Number: 2, Occurrences: 3
Number: 6, Occurrences: 2
Press Enter to quit...
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    int i;
    string input;

    Console.WriteLine("Type repeating numbers, one per line, and I will find them ('quit' to end).");
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Number ('quit' to end): ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(input, out i))
        {
            if(!counts.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                counts.Add(i, 1);  // first time we've seen this number
            }
            else
            {
                counts[i] = counts[i] + 1; // increment the count for this number
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i + " added");
        }
        else if (input != "quit")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Integer");
        }
    } while (input != "quit");

    Console.WriteLine("Results:");
    foreach(KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in counts)
    {
        if (kvp.Value > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number: " + kvp.Key + ", Occurrences: " + kvp.Value);
        }
    }
    Console.Write("Press Enter to quit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```